# Agregar un array dentro de otro Array y verse Json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

dispongo del siguiente codigo

```
$id = '1';
    $stmt = Conexion::getInstance()-> prepare("SELECT titulo, estudio, url, infobox, contenido, user_id, imagen,comentarios, enlaces, contador, status, fecha, id FROM enciclopedia WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt -> bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $resultados = [];
    while ($row = $stmt ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $enciclopedia = [
        "titulo" => $row['titulo'],
        "url" => $row['url'],
        "estudio" => $row['estudio'],
        "infobox" => $row['infobox'],
        "contenido" => $row['contenido'],
        "user_id" => $row['user_id'],
        "imagen" => $row['imagen'],
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "genero" => ""
            ];
    array_push($resultados,$enciclopedia);

    $stmt1 = Conexion::getInstance()-> prepare("SELECT p.tag_type_name, p.tag_type_revien_id, t.tag_id, t.tag_name, t.tag_url FROM enciclopedia_tags t LEFT JOIN enciclopedia_tags_types p ON ( t.tag_id = p.tag_type_name )WHERE p.tag_type_revien_id = :id");
    $stmt1 -> bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt1 -> execute();
            while ($row_p = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $generotag[] = $row_p["tag_name"];
                        }
            $generotag = implode(", ",$generotag);
            $genero2['genero'] = $generotag;

        array_push($resultados,$genero2);
    }

return  json_encode($resultados);
```

El problema es que el array_push me agrega el array como un objeto mas, lo que quiero es que se agregue dentro del json_encode
Asi se ve:

```
[{"titulo":"TEST 01","url":"test","infobox":"Pueba","contenido":"Prueba 2","user_id":1,"imagen":"test.jpg","id":1,"genero":""},{"genero":"ciencia ficci\u00f3n, aventura, fantasia, magia, aventura, hist\u00f3rico"}]
```

Y se deberia verse de esta manera

```
[{"titulo":"TEST 01","url":"test","infobox":"Pueba","contenido":"Prueba 2","user_id":1,"imagen":"test.jpg","id":1,"genero":"ciencia ficci\u00f3n, aventura, fantasia, magia, aventura, hist\u00f3rico"}]
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Te aconsejo que escribas una sola instrucción SQL donde unas las tablas `enciclopedia`, `enciclopedia_tags` y  `enciclopedia_tags_types`. Así, armarás un sólo objeto y habrás optimizado el código, ejecutando una sola consulta. Una de las principales ventajas de las BD es que son **relacionales**, y estás ignorando eso parcialmente en tu código. Unes dos tablas, pero, ¿por qué no unir las tres o las que haga falta, que para eso es la relacionalidad de las BD?

Comment: Se me hizo complicado unir las 3 tablas, pero al final ya no pude solucionarlo, salu2!!

Comment: y si usas: `$resultados[]=$enciclopedia` y lo mismo con `$genero2`